# Meteor not accepting div calls outside of getJson?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, meteor

Very peculiar experience with Meteor.js. My code goes something like so:

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function(){

$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(lingo){
$('.location').text(" " + lingo.zip + ", " + lingo.city);
});
};
```

Basically I am using an API to get JSON info and put it into my `$('.location')` div. This code works. What does not, however, is this code.

```
var tree = $('.location').text();
$('.repeat').text(tree);
```

Specifically, it does not work when I put this code outside my getJSON function. So doing this...

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function(){

$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(lingo){
$('.location').text(" " + lingo.zip + ", " + lingo.city);
});


var tree = $('.location').text();
$('.repeat').text(tree);
};
```

ends with an empty `div class="repeat"`. However, if I reformat like so...

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function(){

$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(lingo){
$('.location').text(" " + lingo.zip + ", " + lingo.city);

var tree = $('.location').text();
$('.repeat').text(tree);

});
};
```

Then suddenly I am able to retrieve the property of my `div class="location"` and put it on my `div class="repeat"`. I am wondering why this is the case.

I do not want to have to start calling my div strings strictly underneath the getJSON function when they contain json stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code for copying location into repeat element is going to execute before initialising of '.location' element.

```
//rendered is old API.
Template.mytemplate.onRendered(function(){

$.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function resultFn(lingo){
  //2. after some time this code will be executed
  $('.location').text(" " + lingo.zip + ", " + lingo.city);
});

  //1. code below will be executed first
  var tree = $('.location').text();
  $('.repeat').text(tree);
});
```

Why? "getJSON" call requires some time be executed, because it uploads some external data via network. So, your callback "resultFn" will be executed with some delay. That's why 2 last lines will be executed first.

Also, put data into template using jquery isn't true Meteor way. The solution I can think about is something like:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class="location">
  {{location}}
  </div>

  <div class="repeat">
  {{location}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And logic:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
     this.location = new ReactiveVar(); //reactive-var package
     var self = this;
     $.getJSON('http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?', function(lingo) {
        self.location.set(lingo.zip + ", " + lingo.city);
     });
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  location: function(){
    return Template.instance().location.get();
  }
});
```

So, now your data renders reactively and you can change it whenever you like by changing reactive variable's value.

Comment: Thanks! This made a lot of sense to me. Also, I am currently looking into replacing my $.getJSON with Meteor's HTTP call, but I am unsure whether this code is supposed to go on my client-side or server. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JasonChen Sometimes you need only look into the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http